# Read detailed testthat log on Travis CI

Tags: r, logging, travis-ci, testthat

I am working on [an R project](https://github.com/richelbilderbeek/Cer2016) that [is tested with Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/richelbilderbeek/Cer2016). When I run the `testthat` tests locally, all tests pass. When those test run on Travis CI, some tests fail.

The problem is that I cannot see the detailed error messages that appear after the tests have run.

I do see the 'top part' of the errors on Travis:

```
ERROR

Running the tests in ‘tests/testthat.R’ failed.
Last 13 lines of output:
  OK: 825 SKIPPED: 0 FAILED: 9
  1. Error: one posterior is added (@test-add_posteriors.R#44) 
  2. Error: two posteriors are added (@test-add_posteriors.R#116) 
  3. Error: three posteriors are added, middle is deleted and added again (@test-add_posteriors.R#197) 
  4. Error: alignment_to_beast_posterior: basic (@test-alignment_to_beast_posterior.R#28) 
  5. Error: are_identical_posteriors: use from local simulation (@test-are_identical_posteriors.R#58) 
  6. Error: do_simulation: use (@test-do_simulation.R#22) 
  7. Error: do_test_simulations: create exact replicate (@test-do_test_simulations.R#9) 
  8. Error: get_posteriors: add one (@test-get_posteriors.R#55) 
  9. Error: get_posteriors: add two (@test-get_posteriors.R#98) 

  Error: testthat unit tests failed
  Execution halted
```

I do not see the 'bottom part' of the error messages on Travis CI. I put an example here, so you know what I hope to see:

```
Failed -------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. Failure: alignment is added (@test-add_alignments.R#49) ---------------------
add_alignments(filename, verbose = TRUE) did not throw an error.
```

I expect/hope that I can get hold of the 'lower part' on Travis CI. I expect/hope there is a log file written somewhere, but I could not find out where.

[EDIT: added this] Note that sometimes I see output like the example output below. This may be a separate question, but I'd also love to see all lines of output there:

```
Last 13 lines of output:
  2: alignment_to_beast_posterior(alignment_dnabin = alignment, base_filename = basefilename, 
         mcmc_chainlength = mcmc_chainlength, rng_seed = new_seed, skip_if_output_present = skip_if_output_present, 
         verbose = verbose)
  3: stop("alignment_to_beast_posterior: ", "file '", beast_trees_filename, "' should have been created")
```